# Как выводить элементы массива в приоритетном порядке , создавая кучу из массива

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Чтобы вытащить элементы из вектора в приоритетном порядке, кроме как сортировать вектор, можно еще превратить его в кучу.
Вот такая простенькая программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#define WHOLE(x) std::begin(x), std::end(x)    
int main()
{   
    constexpr size_t sz = 20;
    std::vector<int> v(sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        v[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }   
    std::make_heap(WHOLE(v));       
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        std::cout << v[0] << ' ';
        std::pop_heap(WHOLE(v));
        v.pop_back();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Как то же самое проделать для массива?

Comment: Заменить `std::begin(x)` на `v`, а `std::end(x)` - на `v + sz`?

Comment: И все? А что это даст? Думаю ничего...

Comment: Все, что нужно сделать - это помнить, что после `pop_heap` размер уменьшился на 1.

Comment: @AnT, нет, размер не уменьшается после pop_heap, а  первый элемент(наибольший) перемещается в конец и сохраняется свойство кучи

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: В том-то и суть, что первый перемещается в конец и *размер кучи уменьшается на 1* (!). Если вы не уменьшите размер на 1, то для "сохранении свойства кучи" придется вернуть максимальный обратно наверх, что сделает всю операцию бессмысленной.

Comment: @AnT,  с этим согласен...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define WHOLE(x, sz) (x), (x + sz)

int main() {
    constexpr size_t sz = 20;
    int v[sz]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        v[i] = rand() % 1000;
    }
    std::make_heap(WHOLE(v, sz));
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        std::cout << v[0] << ' ';
        std::pop_heap(WHOLE(v, sz - i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: да,  точно, а я  почему то пытался  выполнить std::pop_heap(v + i, v + sz));